# post can't reach on target with Heroku - Fixie

Tags: java, rest, heroku, https, proxy

I'm making REST API service with another REST API service.

When I post a request to use external REST API service, the post can't reach on target.
The target host requires static IP address and HTTP protcol, so I use Fixie on Heroku.

I get following messages on heroku.

```
o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {tls}->http://xxxxx.usefixie.com:80->https://my-target-host.com:443: The target server failed to respond
o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {tls}->http://xxxxx.usefixie.com:80->https://my-target-host.com:443 org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: my-target-host.com:443 failed to respond
```

Currentry, the host don't expose access log.

These are my Java code.
Code-A.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/action");
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("my-target-host.com",443,"https");
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

try{
    URL proxyUrl = new URL(System.getenv("FIXIE_URL"));

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl.getHost(), proxyUrl.getPort());
    HttpRoutePlanner routePlanner = new HttpRoutePlanner() {

        @Override
        public HttpRoute determineRoute(HttpHost target, org.apache.http.HttpRequest request,
                org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext context) throws HttpException {
            return new HttpRoute(target, null,  new HttpHost(proxyUrl.getHost(), proxyUrl.getPort()), true);
        }
    };
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();) {

        try {
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(CONTENT_JSON, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            CloseableHttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(targetHost,post);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Code-B.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/action");
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("my-target-host.com",443,"https");
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

try{
    URL proxyUrl = new URL(System.getenv("FIXIE_URL"));
    String userInfo = proxyUrl.getUserInfo();
    String user = userInfo.substring(0, userInfo.indexOf(':'));
    String password = userInfo.substring(userInfo.indexOf(':') + 1);

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(proxyUrl.getHost(),proxyUrl.getPort()),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user,password));

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();) {

        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl.getHost(), proxyUrl.getPort());
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
        post.setConfig(config);

        String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userInfo.getBytes());
        post.setHeader("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth);

        try {
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(CONTENT_JSON, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            CloseableHttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(targetHost,post);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Code-C.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/action");
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("my-tareget-host.com",443,"https");

try{
    URL proxyUrl = new URL(System.getenv("FIXIE_URL"));
    String userInfo = proxyUrl.getUserInfo();
    String user = userInfo.substring(0, userInfo.indexOf(':'));
    String password = userInfo.substring(userInfo.indexOf(':') + 1);

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient_ = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
      httpclient_.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(proxyUrl.getHost(), proxyUrl.getPort()),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));
      HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl.getHost(), proxyUrl.getPort());
      httpclient_.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
      String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userInfo.getBytes());

      post.setEntity(new StringEntity(CONTENT_JSON, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      post.setHeader("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth);

      HttpResponse rsp = httpclient_.execute(targetHost, post);

    } finally {
        httpclient_.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

These code cause same result.
On same environment, this ruby code is reached.

```
RestClient.proxy = ENV['FIXIE_URL'] if ENV['FIXIE_URL']
RestClient.post("https://my-target-host.com/action", CONTENT_JSON, {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
})
```

What's happend on access? What should I modify on Java?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? You can find out by running `heroku run java -version`.

Comment: thanks.Java version is here.
openjdk version "1.8.0_74-cedar14"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-cedar14-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: What version of HttpClient are you using. Seems TLS version related. A newer client might help. Here is an example that works https://github.com/kissaten/proxy-examples

Comment: hmm... httpclient is "httpclient-4.3.6.jar". I modify my code in reference to the link, but I can't. I have 2 defferent - "https", "post". Are these caused?

Comment: I'm having a similar with Google Maps Services Java and Fixie. I've raised an issue there, see https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/160